# d3.js dynamically set node visibility

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3.js I have a force layout with different nodes. All these different nodes are part of different groups. For each group i have one "supernode" which i want to represent all the normal nodes. This is how i define nodes:

```
//Nodes are defined.
            var node = g.selectAll(".node")
                .data(nodes);

            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node");



            //Image is added for each node, depending on what type it is.
            nodeEnter.append("image")
                .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
                    if (d.id == "supernode") {
                        return "../icons/supernodes/" + d.type + ".png";
                    } else {
                        return "../icons/" + d.type + ".png";
                    }
                })
                .attr("x", -25)
                .attr("y", -25)
                .attr("width", 50)
                .attr("height", 50);
                // .style("visibility", function(d) {          
                //     return d.id == "supernode" ? "hidden" : "visible";
                // });
```

I have a button that when i click i want to switch between showing the Supernode and hiding the nodes, or vise versa. I check which one should happen with a bool called "superNodeShown". And i have one method which should toggle the visibility:

```
        var superNodeShown = false;
        function bundleNodes() {
                console.log("before",node);
                if (!superNodeShown){
                        node.style("visibility", function(d) {

                        if (d.id =="supernode") return "visible";
                        else return "hidden";

                    });
                }
                else{
                    node.style("visibility", function(d) {

                        if (d.id =="supernode") return "hidden";
                        else return "visible";
                    });
                }
                superNodeShown = !superNodeShown;

                console.log("after",node);
            }

            //button click event
            d3.select('#buttonTest').on('click', function() {

                bundleNodes();
            });
```

Now when you see the code for defining the nodes, I have commented out the style. This way it works fine, the nodes are toggled on button click. However in this way when i start up the page all the nodes, both normal and supernodes are visible. I would like that on start only the normal nodes are visible (as you can tell by looking at the commented out nodeEnter.style). If i uncomment that part of the code, it does not work anymore.

Comment: what is `node` ? in the code ? is that variable accessible in function `bundleNodes()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems I could find in your code are the following.

- There is a wrong semicolon like this `.attr("height", 50);.style(...` which may be a typo.
- You should hide the node group elements instead of hiding the images alone.

Try this way.

```
nodeEnter.style("visibility", function(d) {          
    return d.id == "supernode" ? "hidden" : "visible";
});
```